# Performance of deleting folder with lots of files on iOS

Tags: ios, performance, delete-file, nsfilemanager

Say I've got a folder in my iOS app's data directory with several thousand small files in it.  Deleting this folder (via `[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath]`) takes a nontrivial amount of time.  But on OS X, deleting a folder with the same contents is very fast.  It seems to simply unlink the folder from the filesystem.  So why does iOS take so long?  What is the difference?

Edit: On an iPad 3, deleting 3 folders with 5,000 to 9,000 files each takes about 35 seconds.  On the simulator running on an older Retina MBP, it takes about 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

> The hierarchical structure that you see is not "real" -- directories
>   are not physical containers for the files that they appear to contain.
>   The directory hierarchy is a carefully maintained fiction.
>
> Irrelevant aside:   The original Mac file system took this a step
>   further -- it made the directory structure   totally a visual fiction
>   -- all of the files were at the root of the (3.5") floppy)   disk, and only *seemed* to be arranged in folders. Thankfully this was
>   supplanted by HFS.
>
> It is better to think of directories/folders as a special kind of file
>   that contains an index to a set of files that it is going to *pretend*
>   to contain.
>
> Conceptually, this works much like classical Cocoa memory management.
>   Each (directory/object) "owns" a set of (files/objects) by reference
>   ("retains" the (file/object)).
>
> When you delete a file from a directory, it is "released". If no other
>   directory has an ownership claim on that file, it is "dealloc'ed".
>
> Your (folder/object) doesn't contain the objects that it "owns". It
>   doesn't really even "own" them -- it just has a "ownership claim" on
>   them.
>
> From Wikipedia's article about Hard Links:
>
> > "a hard link is a directory entry that associates a name with a file on a file system. A directory is itself a special kind of file that
> >     contains a list of such entries."
>
> Note that due to the use of hard links it is possible to have a single
>   physical file that can appear in multiple directories. Each one of
>   those directories owns a reference to the "real" file. Each reference
>   is as "real" as any other. All references have to be "unlinked" for
>   the file to be marked as deleted.
>
> The "file" can even have different "names" in the different
>   directories!
>
> Hard links are the chain  saw of filesystem features -- powerful, but
>   potentially quite dangerous. Note that the OSX GUI provides no means
>   of producing hard links, or even symlinks.

From [this email list item](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Oct/msg00087.html).

Now about iOS

[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath: error:], what it does under the
hood is they iterate through the subdirectories and files and delete
them first. This takes some time. I am interested if it is possible to
do this instantly, without even implicit recursion. Just remove the
directory and the files and subdirectories would disappear?

what you can do is

1. If you're worried about the time this would take and you need an instant results you could rename the folder (which is virtually instantaneous) then remove the renamed folder and it's contents in a background thread.
2. If time is a constraint, try running the delete process in a background thread, if it is not a problem.

Comment: The renaming first is a great idea.  And I'm already doing the delete on a background thread via GCD.  I was just curious why the difference was so large.

Comment: @harsh, no, it's not possible to remove the directory and have the files implicitly removed.  unlink(2) the low level file system operation to remove a link to an inode will fail with EPERM when called on a directory by anybody but root.  rmdir(2) will fail with ENOTEMPTY if the directory is not empty.

Comment: Much of this is plagiarized from [this Apple email list item](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Oct/msg00087.html). Please attribute your source and use blockquotes in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing your tests on device and a Mac, or simulator and Mac.

In the first case the difference is due to the hardware, an iphone is slower than a mac.
In the second case, you should think that is a simulator so the inner mechanism could be different somehow.
What is the difference in sec about the two process?

Comment: On an iPad 3, the deletion (which actually is deleting 3 folders with 5,000 to 9,000 files each) takes about 35 seconds.  On the simulator (i.e. the OS X file system, in this case on an older Retina MBP) it takes about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Is normal you can' t compare an iPhone/iPad hardware to a Mac hardware. As someone said you should run that task on background

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform long running tasks on main thread. Consider you want to remove all the contents of documents directory.

```
- (void) deleteDocumentsDirectoryContents
{
    NSString *folderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error = nil;
    for (NSString *file in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:&error])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
    }
}
```

Call the above function like this.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(deleteDocumentsDirectoryContents) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm already doing it on a background thread, but I was curious why the difference was so large.