# Is FileManager removeItem(atPath:) fast operation?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I have a directory in my app that contains a bunch of files (also in subdirectories) for upload. After I upload the file I delete it but the empty directories remain. I try to deal with them periodically by traversing the content of "root" directory and marking all empty directories for deletion.

Due to the nature of the app I assume that the average number of empty directories is around `50` but it can grow in worst cases to around `1000`.

I remove all marked directories with `FileManager.removeItem(atPath:)` in a loop in main thread:

```
for itemToDeletePath in markedItems {
    try? filemanager.removeItem(atPath: itemToDeletePath)
}
```

Should I be worried about performance of this looped deletion? In general is it "fast" to delete empty directory?

I unfortunately couldn't find any info on performance of deletion operations on iOS (or at least I didn't know how to search this).

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100826/2152616. Tl; dr do this in a background thread.

Comment: @OnurTuna Thanks! Rename then delete in background thread approach is an interesting idea.